# duct tape upvc conservatory leaks

Tags: leak, duct-tape

I have an old conservatory that is white upvc. Along the joints across the roof it leaks. I want to know if I can stop these leaks by putting tape like this along the joins inside (not outside) (it would be stuck to the white upvc either side of the leak, across the join): "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Gorilla-Tape-Range-Black-Clear-Silver-Tough-Wide-Handy-White-Mounting/360993674393?var=630333846760&epid=1339840406&hash=item540ce65499:m:mRURLaUN70-STe0IQPIMrAg".

To be clear, I'm not concerned with how it looks, or how long it lasts, just so that it lasts for the rest of the winter. I have tried sealant in the past and all that does is redirect the leak further along. I'm hoping that tape will fully seal it. It's not a huge leak, just many pinprick leaks along a 3m join.

Comment: What is a conservatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a temporary fix gorilla tape would be my choice. Make sure the area that you are going to seal is wiped clean prior to putting the tape up. Since there is no real pressure the tape should hold on the inside to stop the leak.

Comment: Thanks. I really wanted to check that I wasn't doing something really dumb - which I have a habit of doing. I'll go ahead and order some now.